# Messages while booting 14.04

Tags: boot, 14.04

When booting Ubuntu 14.04 after the purple screen it goes to a black screen with these messages:

```
[ 12.207377] snd_hda_codec: module has bad taint, not creating trace events
[ 12.200502] snd_hda_controller: module has bad taint, not creating trace even
[ 12.500765] i915_bdw: exports duplicate symbol i915_release_power_well
[ 12.598736] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:00.0: Error request power-well from i915
```

These messages are shown for a short time, and after the computer boots everything seems to work properly except freezing on suspend which I posted about before.

How to fix/remove these messages?

Answer (score 0):

Likewise for me. And I have the suspending problem too. However, the workaround for the suspending issue is to:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf`

and find the line that says "HandleLidSwitch=" and erase what is there, and put "HandleLidSwitch=ignore"

Save and reboot. You should be able to close your lid and open it without hanging issues.

I have a Compal JHL90.

Comment: The workaround didn't go for me. It just skip log in screen goes to the desktop and then freezes (and fans start working loudly).
This link will show you everything that terminal shows when i enter  command you gave me. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7509280/

Comment: You have to take the hash key (#) off before the HandleLidSwitch, or it comments it out and makes no difference.

Comment: I removed it, it doesn't make no difference.